# how to pass data from one page to another in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-phone-7, cordova

I Tried to pass data from one html page to another one i tried two methods:

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{   
    window.location = "newsList.html?Title="+clicked_id;
}
```

and also tried

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{   
    window.localStorage.setItem("Title", clicked_id);
    window.location = "newsList.html";
}
```

but both does not working in windows phone

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery Mobile you could use the $.mobile.changePage method wich should allow you to keep the local storage.

[JqueryForum - localStorage not persisting in jQuery 1.3.0 (Windows Phone 8)](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/localstorage-not-persisting-in-jquery-1-3-0-windows-phone-8)

Also make sure you use the getItem method to retrieve data from local storage as in Windows Phone 7 dot notation is not avaiable.

[Phonegap docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

use
`window.location.assign` instead of `window.location`